# Smart pointer choice for custom UI element usage

Tags: c++, user-interface, pointers, c++11

I'm building a cross-platform mobile app that's front-end is made from scratch. The short philosophy is this:

- Every UI element directly or indirectly inherits from `Element`. It has basic data structures for size, position on the screen and so on.
- UI controls can inherit intermediaries that inherit `Element` like `Touchable`, `Scrollable`, etc. Intermediary inheritance from class `Element` is virtual.
- Every `Element` descendant can have an arbitrary amount of sub-elements.

Example:

```
class Touchable : public virtual Element { ... };
class HasText : public virtual Element { ... };

class Button : public Touchable, public HasText { ... };

class LoginView : public Element {
    Button* _btnLogin;
    TextBox* _txtPassword;
    ...
};
```

`Element` has an `std::vector<???_ptr<Element>>` that holds all the elements. It is used like this:

```
LoginView::LoginView(...) {
    _btnLogin = std::make_???<Button>();
    _btnLogin.setText("Login");
    _btnLogin.setFont("Helvetica"); // initialize
    ...
    addSubview(_btnLogin); // add to vector
}

void LoginView::_someOtherFunc() {
    _btnLogin->isVisible = false;  // use some time later
}
```

During construction of a view, a new instance of the `Button` is created and initialized but it's only drawn when added to the hierarchy (vector). **But** can be used any time later (so `unique_ptr` is out of the question, since I would have to move it to the vector, thus "losing" its ownership in `View`). Also when the object is removed from the vector, it shouldn't be deleted but if it get's deleted in the `View` it **should not be** valid in the vector (removing it from the vector only suspends its drawing).

The question is: **which smart pointer type would fit best in this situation?** Or maybe there's a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: `shared_ptr<>` and `weak_ptr<>`

Answer (score 1):

So your `View`s are the resource managers here, ie they are responsible for allocating UI elements and deleting some of them during the lifetime of the UI depending on interaction I imagine.

I don't understand how/why all elements are stored in a vector in the class `Element` then?

Generally speaking from what I understand, the resource managers (ie the `Views`) should create shared pointers, which they can exchange between them I assume (shared ownership), and the "display" vector (the one that controls the drawing) should store weak pointers. That way whenever drawing your loop runs over the vector it can check and remove elements that have been destroyed. For that reason I would also advise not to use a `vector` but rather a `list` so you can easily and cheaply insert/remove/iterate over elements to be drawn.